# Draw rectangle on mousedown event

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I have a basic zoomable and pannable canvas build in Fabric.js. I need to draw a rectangle on every mousedown event at the clicked coordinate position. The problem happens when the canvas is transformed from it's initial state - the drawing is not accurate because the coordinates must be transformed with the new matrix.

How can I transform the coordinates from the mouse event using the new matrix?

Here is the code I am using. Thanks

```
canvas.on('mouse:down', function (opt) {
  const evt = opt.e;
  const p = new fabric.Rect({
    left: opt.e.offsetX,
    top: opt.e.offsetY,
    fill: 'red',
    width: 30,
    height: 30,
  });
  canvas.add(p);
});
```

**Update 1:** I found a method to transform points (fabric.util.transformPoint()), but 
the transformed points were not correct according to the canvas context.

```
  const evt = opt.e;
  const point = new fabric.Point(opt.e.offsetX, opt.e.offsetY);
  const transformedPoint = fabric.util.transformPoint(point, this.viewportTransform);
  const p = new fabric.Rect({
    left: transformedPoint.x,
    top: transformedPoint.y,
    fill: 'red',
    width: 30,
    height: 30,
  });
  this.add(p);
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'it isn't working for me'?

Comment: Sorry, I meant that the transformed points were not correct according to the canvas context (using fabric.util.transformPoint())

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved it using fabric.util.transformPoint() using an inverted matrix. Here is the code for transforming a point in the canvas to a point in the canvas context.

```
  const point = new fabric.Point(offsetX, offsetY);
  const invertedMatrix = fabric.util.invertTransform(canvas.viewportTransform)
  const transformedPoint = fabric.util.transformPoint(point, invertedMatrix);
```